# How to recover deleted files that were deleted during merging

Tags: django, git, merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I was trying to delete all the migration files on the master branch.  Git prompted:

```
error: Merging is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
```

since I did not need the migration files, I typed:

```
git rm . -r
```

Git prompted:

```
error: the following files have changes staged in the index:
/middleware.py
project_management/models.py
sales/migrations/0001_initial.py
```

(use --cached to keep the file, or -f to force removal)

Thinking that the conflicts are just due to those migration files, I typed:

```
git rm . -r -f
```

Now, git has removed ALL my files, including models, templates, views, static files, etc.

```
rm '.gitignore'
rm 'accounts/__init__.py'
rm 'accounts/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc'
rm 'accounts/__pycache__/backends.cpython-36.pyc'
rm 'accounts/admin.py'
rm 'accounts/apps.py'
rm 'accounts/backends.py'
rm 'accounts/forms/__init__.py'
rm 'accounts/forms/authenticate.py'
rm 'accounts/forms/register.py'
rm 'accounts/migrations/0001_initial.py'
rm 'accounts/migrations/__init__.py'
rm 'accounts/models.py'
rm 'accounts/templates/login.html'
rm 'accounts/templates/signup.html'
rm 'accounts/tests.py'
rm 'accounts/urls.py'
rm 'accounts/views.py'
```

Now, when I do

```
git status
```

It tells me this:
    On branch master
All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
  (use "git commit" to conclude merge)

Changes to be committed:

```
    deleted:    .gitignore
    deleted:    accounts/__init__.py
    deleted:    accounts/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc
    deleted:    accounts/__pycache__/backends.cpython-36.pyc
    deleted:    accounts/admin.py
    deleted:    accounts/apps.py
    deleted:    accounts/backends.py
    deleted:    accounts/forms/__init__.py
    deleted:    accounts/forms/authenticate.py
    deleted:    accounts/forms/register.py
    deleted:    accounts/migrations/0001_initial.py
    deleted:    accounts/migrations/0002_auto_20170212_1028.py
    deleted:    accounts/migrations/__init__.py
    deleted:    accounts/models.py
    deleted:    accounts/templates/login.html
    deleted:    accounts/templates/signup.html
    deleted:    accounts/tests.py
    deleted:    accounts/urls.py
    deleted:    accounts/views.py
    ...
    Untracked files:
    (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    accounts/
    commonapp/
```

There are more than 10 apps, with more than 50 models, etc. but for the sake simplicity, I have not list them all here.

Is there a way to undo these deletions?  This is months worth of my time, so I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git reset --hard` will recover the files for you. It will also remove *all* changes that are staged. So if you've anything you want to keep, copy those files out before the reset.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough Allen!  I was mentally preparing myself for a loss of a few months worth of development work. Thank you!